# Simple Pagination?

Tags: jquery, pagination

Basically, i have a gallery which already limits the number of items to 30, but rather than limiting, i would like to have a "next and Prev" button on either side to basically add or swap lists onced pressed.

I'm thinking pretty simple, just an arrow button, once it's pressed it simply slides and fades out the first page and slides in and fades in the second and so on.

If possible, is it able loop? as in if it's reached the end and they click next, it just adds in more up to the limit of 30?

If it helps, Here's my current site: www.shannonhochkins.com

Comment: if you post what methods have you tried to your question, answering process will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show gallery's example for swapping next object but i can help with pagination problem easly: I have asked the similar question this week; [How to create simple next and prev trigger button for slider's pagination buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934691/how-to-create-simple-next-and-prev-button-for-slider-s-trigger-thumbs)

**[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/merk8/33/)** and here is Aaron Romine's answer:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if($("li.active").next().length > 0){
        $("li.active").removeClass("active").next("li").addClass("active");
    }
});
$(".prev").click(function(){
    if($("li.active").prev().length > 0){
        $("li.active").removeClass("active").prev("li").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this has the triggers, but it doesn't have anything to tell it what length or what lists it needs to paginate?

Comment: mate it depends on what will you gonna use with and you didn't define that section.

Comment: Hi @barlasapaydin, I did mention that it has to just limit to 30 per page :( That's all I need though! Just a limit of that per page! Sorry buddy if you missed that