# Pagination with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, jsp, pagination, jquery-pagination

I was trying to add the pagination functionality to my jsp. I have used the following codes. But only `Prev  Next` link is showing. all the records are listing in the same page.
Why it is happening?? Is there any other easy way to do pagination.?

```
<table align="right">
  <tr>
  <td class="cls2">
  <div id="page" class="page">
    <a href="" class="prev cls3"> <img src="/prev.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0">Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="pdisplay" ></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href=""  class="next cls3">Next<img src="/next.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" border="0"> </a>
  </div> 
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="cls" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"  id="resultTbl">
 <tbody> <thead>
 <tr>
  <th >Select</th>
  <th><span id="isp" class="cls1"><%=request.getParameter("user")%></span></th>
 </tr></thead>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>



jQuery I used :

<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js/jquery.tablesorter.pagerquote.js"></script>
   <script defer="defer">
    $("#resultTbl")
    .tablesorter()
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#page")}); 
</script>
```

Comment: did you get any console error?

Comment: try this http://neoalchemy.org/tablePagination.html

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934691/how-to-create-simple-next-and-prev-trigger-button-for-sliders-pagination-button

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the container of your table,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
   .tablesorter() 
   .tablesorterPager({container: $("#page_container")}); 
});
```

Also i have poted the jsfiddle with working copy:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcatD/

Also check for the following requirements:

jQuery (1.2.1 or higher)

Firefox 2+,
Internet Explorer 6+,
Safari 2+,
Opera 9+,

Comment: When I removed the `<tbody>` from the code it is working fine.. I don't know why!

Comment: @log_in Because you have opened tbody but not closed it...thats not an incomplete htnl :)