# jQuery- Next and Previous not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have followed the solution in this page. 
[How to create simple next and prev trigger button for slider's pagination buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934691/how-to-create-simple-next-and-prev-trigger-button-for-sliders-pagination-button)

But It's not working when I try like this because it's not change the 'selected-active' to another.

```
$('.previous, .next').on('click', function() {
    if ($(".selected-active")[$(this).attr('class')]().index()!=-1)
    $(".selected-active").removeClass('selected-active')[$(this).attr('class')]().addClass('selected-active');
});
```

HTML :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="previous"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>Previous</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bottom">
        <div class="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>Next</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <ul class="container">
                <li class="section-container"><h6>Topic: Test</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item selected-active">
                            <a>
                             <span class="title">part 1: Introduction</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                            <span class="title" >Part 2 : Content</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="container">
                <li class="section-container"><h6>Topic: Test 2</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                             <span class="title">part 1: Introduction</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                            <span class="title" >Part 2 : Content</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: should be seeing an error thrown since jQuery has no method `previous()`

Comment: hmm.I don't know how to do,.so, can help me to improve my jquery code?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do ? What should happen when you click on next or previous ? I see that you're trying to do something with `selected-active`, adding or removing that class but it's not clear from your code. If you can explain your intent, we can try and change the code accordingly :)

Comment: Oh,I just want to create like this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934691/how-to-create-simple-next-and-prev-trigger-button-for-sliders-pagination-button

Comment: You deleted your other question before I could post this jQuery version of your code with delegation on the li item https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1qL1tsk0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  var i = $(".item").index($(".selected-active"));
  i = i > $('.item').length-1 ? 0 : i-1 ;
  $(".item").removeClass('selected-active').eq(i).addClass('selected-active');
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  var i = $(".item").index($(".selected-active"));
  i = i < $('.item').length-1 ? i+1 : 0 ;
  $(".item").removeClass('selected-active').eq(i).addClass('selected-active');
});
```

```css
.selected-active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>Previous</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bottom">
        <div class="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>Next</div>
    </div>

<br/>

    <div class="row">
            <ul class="container">
                <li class="section-container"><h6>Topic: Test</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item selected-active">
                            <a>
                             <span class="title">part 1: Introduction</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                            <span class="title" >Part 2 : Content</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
             <ul class="container">
                <li class="section-container"><h6>Topic: Test 2</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                             <span class="title">part 1: Introduction</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a>
                            <span class="title" >Part 2 : Content</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks,your code is working,but how to fix if I add another topic like this
http://jsfiddle.net/merk8/102/

Comment: Oh,thanks,It's working,I think I found the solution using this code :D

Answer (score 2):

The methods you want are `prev()` and `next()` so since the class doesn't match `prev` can do the following

```
$('.previous, .next').on('click', function() {
    var traverse = $(this).hasClass('next') ? 'next' : 'prev';
    if ($(".selected-active")[traverse]().index()!=-1)
    $(".selected-active").removeClass('selected-active')[traverse]().addClass('selected-active');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y5db3j9y/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: A very short, elegant solution. I did essentially the same thing but this is much friendlier than mine. +1

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl ,the code is working nice if add some li,but how to jump to select another topic like this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/y5db3j9y/3/

Comment: Can use same concept by jumping across the containers  http://jsfiddle.net/y5db3j9y/4/ I'm guessing since you already have nested `<ul>` will likely have more than one main `<li>` in each `container` and will need a third step in here also

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished fairly simply using the `next()` and `prev()` functions:

```
$('.previous, .next').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("previous") && $(".selected-active").prev().length) {
        $(".selected-active").removeClass('selected-active').prev().addClass('selected-active');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("next") && $(".selected-active").next().length) {
        $(".selected-active").removeClass('selected-active').next().addClass('selected-active');
    }
    console.log($(".selected-active").text().trim());
});
```

This code uses the `.hasClass()` method to check which button was pressed, and then checks to see if there is an element before or after the `selected-active` element (using `.next().length` and `.prev().length`). It then removes the `selected-active` class from the element that currently has that class and applies it to the next or previous item if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it does not change the current element. The code outputs to the console the content of the `selected-active` element each time either button is pressed.

https://jsfiddle.net/636k980b/1/
You can view the console output using F12 developer tools.